# String64 para imagem em VueJS

Tags: imagem, vue.js, base64, webcam

Estou recebendo uma string codificada em base 64 do banco de dados e quero que ela renderize como uma imagem na tela, a minha dúvida é:

**Basta configurar o `:src=` com o a variável que contém a string base64 ou precisa de algum tratamento antes de atribuir ao `:src=`??**

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
   <q-toolbar color="light-blue-10">
     <q-toolbar-title>Webcam</q-toolbar-title>
   </q-toolbar>
   <webcam ref="webcam"></webcam>
   <img :src="img" style="width: 640px;height: 480px;"/>
   <q-btn color="light-blue-10" @click="photo">
     <q-icon name="photo camera" />Capturar
   </q-btn>
   <q-btn color="light-blue-10" @click="enviar"><q-icon 
     name="send"/>Enviar Foto</q-btn>
   <q-btn color="light-blue-10" @click="verFoto"><q-icon 
     name="person"/>Buscar Foto</q-btn>
   <img :src="imagem" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"/>
 </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
  import {
    QLayout,
    QToolbar,
    QToolbarTitle,
    QBtn,
    QIcon
  } from 'quasar'
  import Webcam from 'vue-web-cam/src/webcam.vue'
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
  components: {
    QLayout,
    QToolbar,
    QToolbarTitle,
    Webcam,
    QBtn,
    QIcon
  },
  data () {
    return {
      img: null,
      imagem: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    photo () {
      this.img = this.$refs.webcam.capture()
    },
    enviar () {
      let foto = this.img
      console.log(foto)
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/server/foto',
        params: foto
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    },
    verFoto () {
      let self = this
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/server/verfoto',
        params: 'foto'
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        self.imagem = response.data[0]
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Teoricamente é só colocar a variável. Depende de como a imagem está vindo pra você, mas a princípio, só substituir a variável.

Comment: Foi o que eu fiz, eu busquei a string do mongo e coloquei em um array, depois enviei para o cliente na response da requisição e só atribuí a variável da posição desejada do array. Formule uma resposta para que eu possa aceitar e que pessoas que também tem essa duvida possam esclarecê-la aqui... Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teoricamente é só colocar a variável. Depende de como a imagem está vindo pra você, mas a princípio, só substituir a variável.

Answer (score 1):

Reabrindo o tópico, eu estava com o mesmo problema, é preciso colocar o valor da variável assim - foto: require("./caminho.png"). segue um exemplo simples.

```
           <div class="valign-wrapper">
              <img v-bind:src="item.foto" id="imgContato"/>
              <div class="col s9 m9 l9">
                <a v-if="pend_dadosPessoais > 0" href="#!" class="secondary-content">
                  <span class="new badge blue">pendentes</span>
                </a>
                <span class="black-text truncate">{{item.nome}}</span>
                <p class="truncate grey-text ultra-small">{{item.ultimaMsgn}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

variável ->

```
item:[{
          nome: 'Jony Alan',
          numero: '15988195946',
          foto: require('./images/foto1.jpg'),
          ultimaMsgn: "Salve Stackoverflow",
          hora: '15:33',
          alerts: '1',
        },]
```